# Outer join not working for an existing query

Tags: sql, oracle

In the below query, I want all those person numbers that do not have records in pay_dir_cards_f and hence in corresponding pay_dir_card_components_f,
pay_dir_comp_details_f.

I have added the outer join below still am not getting the above required records. Instead I am getting records that are in the table pay_dir_cards_f.
How can i modify the outer join in the below query.

Also, please note yes I do know this join style is an old one and I should use the new convention instead but I have to update an existing query hence not using it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT papf.person_number, 
                        PAPF.effective_start_date, 
                        PAPF.effective_end_date ,
                        paam.ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER 
        FROM   per_all_people_f papf, 
               per_all_assignments_m paam, 
               pay_pay_relationships_dn pprd, 
               pay_rel_groups_dn prgd, 
               pay_dir_cards_f pdcf, 
               pay_dir_card_components_f pdccf1, 
               pay_dir_comp_details_f pdcdf1 
        WHERE  SYSDATE BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date AND 
                               papf.effective_end_date 
               AND paam.person_id = papf.person_id 
               AND paam.effective_latest_change = 'Y' 
               AND paam.assignment_type IN ( 'E', 'C' ) 
               AND pprd.person_id = papf.person_id 
               --And PPRD.LEGISLATIVE_DATA_GROUP_ID = PLDGV.LEGISLATIVE_DATA_GROUP_ID  
               AND pprd.payroll_stat_unit_id = paam.legal_entity_id 
               AND prgd.payroll_relationship_id = pprd.payroll_relationship_id 
               AND prgd.assignment_id = paam.assignment_id 
               AND prgd.group_type = 'A' 
               AND pdcf.payroll_relationship_id(+) = 
                   prgd.payroll_relationship_id 
               AND Trunc(SYSDATE) BETWEEN paam.effective_start_date AND 
                                          paam.effective_end_date 
               AND Trunc(SYSDATE) BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date AND 
                                          papf.effective_end_date 
               AND Trunc(SYSDATE) BETWEEN pdcf.effective_start_date AND 
                                          pdcf.effective_end_date 
               AND pdccf1.dir_card_id(+) = pdcf.dir_card_id
               AND pdcdf1.dir_card_comp_id(+) = pdccf1.dir_card_comp_id 

               AND Trunc(SYSDATE) BETWEEN pdcdf1.effective_start_date AND 
                                          pdcdf1.effective_end_date 
               AND pdcdf1.effective_start_date BETWEEN 
                   pdccf1.effective_start_date AND pdccf1.effective_end_date 
        ORDER  BY papf.person_number
```

Comment: I feel the query is half done, as you are left joining then you get all data from that table (pdcf) to respective to join condition. Unless you specify it take columns that are null, it takes all data. Give filter at end saying pdcf.specific column is NULL; Can give it a try

Comment: Please use modern JOIN syntax, available since SQL-92, that is 27 years ago. Few people can read this syntax nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are looking to `OUTER JOIN` on `pay_dir_cards_f` and that it is not happening as you expect.

Old-style join and bad formatting make the query difficult to read... When scaning your query for the part that relate to the `pay_dir_cards_f` join conditions, one condition seems problematic:

```
AND Trunc(SYSDATE) BETWEEN pdcf.effective_start_date AND pdcf.effective_end_date
```

I suspect that Oracle is able to do an `OUTER JOIN` because of (at least) this condition. There are serious limitations and warnings againts the use of old joins, especially `OUTER JOIN`s, which are, for example [documented in the 10g manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm).

I strongly recommend that you rewrite your query to use non-ancient joins. That would probably just make your problem disappear.

As a sign of good will, please find below a first attempt to rebuild (and reformat) the query. You would need to review it and probably fix a few hitches, but that should be a pretty good starting point:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    papf.person_number, 
    papf.effective_start_date, 
    papf.effective_end_date ,
    paam.ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER 
FROM   
    per_all_people_f papf 
    INNER JOIN per_all_assignments_m paam
        ON  paam.person_id = papf.person_id 
        AND paam.effective_latest_change = 'Y' 
        AND paam.assignment_type IN ( 'E', 'C' ) 
        AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN paam.effective_start_date AND paam.effective_end_date        
    INNER JOIN pay_pay_relationships_dn pprd
        ON  pprd.person_id = papf.person_id 
        -- AND pprd.legislative_data_group_id = pldgv.legislative_data_group_id  
        AND pprd.payroll_stat_unit_id = paam.legal_entity_id 
    INNER JOIN pay_rel_groups_dn prgd
        ON  prgd.payroll_relationship_id = pprd.payroll_relationship_id 
        AND prgd.assignment_id = paam.assignment_id 
        AND prgd.group_type = 'A' 
    INNER JOIN pay_dir_cards_f pdcf
        ON  pdcf.payroll_relationship_id = prgd.payroll_relationship_id 
        AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN pdcf.effective_start_date AND pdcf.effective_end_date 
    LEFT JOIN pay_dir_card_components_f pdccf1
        ON  pdccf1.dir_card_id = pdcf.dir_card_id
        AND pdccf1.dir_card_id = pdcf.dir_card_id   
    LEFT JOIN pay_dir_comp_details_f pdcdf1 
        ON  TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN pdcdf1.effective_start_date AND pdcdf1.effective_end_date 
        AND pdcdf1.dir_card_comp_id = pdccf1.dir_card_comp_id 
WHERE  
    SYSDATE BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date AND  papf.effective_end_date 
    AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date AND papf.effective_end_date
ORDER  BY papf.person_number
```